# countries coming twice in google map

Tags: google-maps

I'm using jquery ui map plugin to display google map but at zoom level 1 we are able to view some country twice in map . in map "https://maps.google.co.uk/" , we are not able to produce this scenario so can someone please tell me in how we can achive this ?

Comment: var map = jQuery('#map_canvas').gmap('get', 'map');
 map.fitBounds(new google.maps.LatLngBounds(new google.maps.LatLng(-59.53, -168.75),new google.maps.LatLng(72.39, 178.59)));

Comment: i tried with above code but somehow it is not completly working

Comment: seems view port is not correct option , I possiblity need to set number of KM to be display in google map

Comment: var map = jQuery('#map_canvas').gmap('get', 'map'); 
var bounds1 = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(new google.maps.LatLng(-2.98, 2.61),new google.maps.LatLng(0.73, 0.86));
map.fitBounds(bounds1); 
map.setCenter(bounds1.getCenter());

Comment: seems nothing is working . only option left is set minimum zoom level.

Comment: for now , workaround solution worked for me (i.e. set minimum zoom level).